# Python datetime countdown miscalculates remaining time

Tags: python, datetime

```
delta = datetime.now() - datetime(2020, 3, 24)
yeardif = round(delta.days/365)
yearRem = round(delta.days%365)
mondif = round(yearRem/30)
daydif = round(delta.days%365%30)
```

The code is for a countdown timer. Variable "delta" should output the time difference in days using

```
.days
```

but something about the equation is wrong because the output is incorrect.

Comment: What do you get as output and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) without supplying `ndigits` for the fractions? That returns an `int`...

Comment: let me try and change that MrFuppes see if it fixes it edit: your

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at time differences in terms of time remaining you wouldn‘t want to round your values but rather use floor() instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The code is for a countdown timer. Variable "delta" should output the time difference in days using .days

If you just want the time difference in days this is all you need:

```
delta = datetime.now() - datetime(2020, 3, 24)
days = delta.days + delta.seconds / 86400
```

This will give you 13.35866 days (13 whole days, plus 0.35866 days).  This is preferable to dividing by 30 and 365 since this method accounts for differing days per month and leap years.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for pointing that out.  I was just confused.  Thank for correcting; will edit my answer.